# How can I have a Very secure Ubuntu Desktop system

Tags: security

How can I have a Very secure Ubuntu Desktop system and where is the best place online to learn about hardening Linux, not just Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To harden Ubuntu servers, there are a number of packages that can be found with:

```
apt-cache search harden-
```

to install all of them, simply use:

```
apt-get install harden-*
```

and start reading the hardening documentation now installed on your system in `/usr/share/doc/harden-doc`

For more information, visit the [Securing Debian](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-manual/index.en.html) Manual.

Comment: But what if their all answers provided are correct,  what do you do then

Comment: You come back when you have more reputation and you upvote them (the little grey arrow above the number "0") and that is why your question is going to be closed: there are too many good (**and bad**) answers

Answer (score 6):

Basic rules of computer security: strong passwords, have a firewall set up, don't click on something you're not sure about, and don't log in as admin/root unless you 100% have to.

Viruses aren't as much of a problem on linux as on windows, but social engineering in emails, javascript in browsers, and malicious links are still there.

Among other things, set up an admin password on your router; [see my answer on this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/544064/295286).

A good place to start learning about security is the movie "Blackhat", now in theaters (yes, seriously). There's also learning from other perspective, from intruder's perspective. You can search online for tutorials on basic pentesting/ethical hacking and books.

Here's some of my favorite sources to start you off on reading about security.

1. [cyberciti blog](http://cyberciti.biz/)
2. [security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/)
3. https://serverfault.com/
4. [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BasicSecurity)

Answer (score -2):

well. . . . when it comes to linux, it is already secure. it has it's own built in firewalls to keep "sensitive" documents from being touched. if you want more security, i would go with something like Avast for ubuntu. you can get the installation file from the website and then you need to download WINE and or WINE Tricks. when you finish downloading avast, right click over the file and click on "run in WINE." from there it's just a matter of registering either the free version or just buy a protection plan. This is if you wanted something like Avast. i am also putting a link to 5 of the best antivirus programs for ubuntu.

[Top 5 AntiVirus programs for Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntufree.com/top-5-antivirus-apps-for-ubuntu-14-04-and-14-10/)

Now, for the firewall. You also need to make sure you have a firewall, not just antivirus. I will post two links for the firewall. one is to 'harden' Ubuntu's built-in firewall and the other is for other firewall software that you can download (mind you, they are the best as well, and FREE!!!!).

[How to configure Ubuntu built-in firewall](http://www.howtogeek.com/115116/how-to-configure-ubuntus-built-in-firewall/)

http://tecmint.com/open-source-security-firewalls-for-linux-systems/

Comment: No. Absolutely no.