# ShopGlider Deals has taken over my Chrome Browser in Ubuntu 14.04 HOW DO I REMOVE IT?

Tags: google-chrome, malware

PLEASE HELP!  Does anyone know how to completely remove the ShopGlider Ads/Deals malware from Chrome?  I'm running Chrome Version 42.0.2311.135 (64-bit)  And Ubuntu MATE 14.04.

There are no extensions installed in chrome that should have had this malware bundled with it, and there are no extensions showing as ShopGlider, so the usual Windows instructions for removing this are useless for Linux.

I can not remember exactly when I started noticing these shopping ads popup in my Chrome browser, but they seem to be getting worse and Chrome is running slower and using more memory than usual.

There are hundreds of sites explaining how to remove this from a Windows system, but I can not find even one telling how to remove this virus from a Linux machine! Even a search for ShopGlider on here turns up 0 results!

I really want this garbage off my machine, and I know I'm not the only one running Ubuntu that has this problem.

Really hope someone can help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not affected, so only comment, but have you already deleted ~/.config/chromium/  (this should reset chromium, delete all extensions, saved passswords bookmarks etc)

Comment: I am using Chrome, not Chromium... thus ~/.config/chromium/ does not exist.  I do have a ~/.config/google-chrome/ directory, but there really should be a way to "surgically" remove this malware rather than having to blast my whole Chrome setup :-(

Comment: Even though I can understand that, as a first step I would rename that folder to see if that helps. Then I would copy bookmarks etc. from the old in the new folder one by one rather than in bulk to see what the culprit is.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/579949/how-to-remove-malware/579957) for a short guide on removing malware. In addition to what answers were posted in that thread I would recommend that you do a full reset on all of your browsers just to be safe.

Also, I found [this thread](http://www.linux.org/threads/malware-and-antivirus-systems-for-linux.4455/) on linux.org that discusses different anti-virus software so you could choose the most suitable one to install for yourself. I personally installed COMODO Antivirus a few weeks ago and I currently haven't had any negative experiences with it.

Note that with some anti-virus software you will have to manually enable detection of PUP's (Potentially Unwanted Programs). This will greater the chances of the AV software detecting something like you are describing.

Hope this has helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Chrome menu > More Tools > Task Manager
and terminate all processes extensions, as there is an extension which is preventing you from entering the configuration page for extensions.

Then, go to the extensions page.

Eliminate the extension that you think is causing problems.

If you have removed an extension that is not the culprit, you have to repeat the steps above and try another extension that you think may be guilty.