# remove pop up ad from ads.matte.com malware from ubuntu!

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, 15.04, malware

A malware pops up `http://ad.adsmatte.com/<random string>` and annoys me every time i click on a link. It has also denied me access to youtube. The youtube page is completly disoriented and doesnt play any video.
I tried to reinstall the chromium browser and all, but they were futile. My browsing speed has also declined. Please help! Below is how youtube is displayed!
[image]

Comment: Is this a really **Windows** issue, or do you think you have a **virus** under Ubuntu? *Same (Windows) issue on an Android forum:* http://forums.androidcentral.com/general-help-how/528965-how-get-rid-adsmatte-com-adware.html

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 15.04 ... Since i have low reputation i could't post picture...

Comment: You can search "http://ad.adsmatte.com pop up" in google and you'll find lots of solution that were written within 2-3 days back from today...But all of them have talked about how to solve in windows OS... I want to solve this problem in my Ubuntu OS...

Comment: **Please confirm:** Is this affecting both **Chromium** and **Firefox**, or just Chromium?

Comment: have you attempted to remove/disable any suspect *Extensions* in Chrome/Chromium? See: http://www.antivirusgateway.com/cant-delete-adsmatte-com-how-to-get-rid-of-adsmatte-com-ads-completely-in-your-pc/

Comment: It has affected all browsers. Even if I download a random new browser, I still get the pop up.

Comment: I have added picture to this question. Have a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does not appear to be an OS related issue. I would recommend you to read this http://www.quora.com/How-do-I-stop-AdsMatte-spam-popups-and-ads

Basically it is an attack on/via your router. You should hard reset it. A lot of computers on my intranet got affected. I got rid of it that way.

Comment: It is not an os related issue? The removal methods all over the internet are specifically for windows users. I tried uninstalling all the browsers and installing them back! But none were of any use.

Comment: No it's not. I was surprised to see it on Ubuntu as well. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and I had the same problem. Also the youtube page.

Comment: Thank you so much! Hard reset actually solved the problem!

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/579949/how-to-remove-malware/579957) for a short guide on removing malware. In addition to what answers were posted in that thread I would recommend that you do a full reset on all of your browsers just to be safe.

It is not that common for non Windows systems to get infections but it is still a possibility that they can get in, and the most common types of infections I have seen in my experience would be a type of browser hijacker.

Hope this has helped :)

Answer (score -1):

THE ONLY SOLUTION TO THIS PROBLEM IS:
there is no solution of removing this adsmatte without hurting your log file so it is necessary to first reset your modem if you are using a wifi router because the main problem causing by this virus is that it changes your ip address. after reseting your wifi you have to factory reset your phone or any device which has been infected because this virus launches a script which goes under the operating system's log files and cant be deleted without system format. it is totally useless to remove browser or clear cache. i was having the same problem and i did everything i can and atlast i did what i explained above. but pay attention on reseting every device which has been infected as if YOU may reset your wifi but while connectimg the same device through it will cause the problem to repeat itself. so dont worry and follow the above instructions :)

Comment: I doubt that there's no solution, everything the man creates can be broken. ;)