# Is it possible to see what processes did last mounted USB device?

Tags: usb, malware, monitoring, history

Is it possible to see what last mounted USB device? I am afraid, that last device infected my ubuntu machine and want to find out something about that device.

Answer (score 0):

The Linux operating system, and many applications that run on it, do a lot of logging. These logs are invaluable for monitoring and troubleshooting your system. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/viewing-and-monitoring-log-files#1-overview

Comment: could you clarify the answer? I knew, that operating system do a lot of logging and there are huge documentations to read, but maybe you could post commands and explain what should I look for? It was big chip something like 4G USB dongle, how can I check if it not installed any malicious software?

Comment: you can install malicious removal like as that mentioned 
 in this answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/579949/how-to-remove-malware